# Directly connect two docker containers

Tags: docker, networking, containers, virtualization

What I intend to do is make all the traffic that goes to my http server (C2)needs to go through a black box container (C1). Making the default gateway of C2 the eth1 of C1.

I tried to do this but I couldn't find a way, because even if i create a new network a new bridge will be created and the 2 containers won't be directly connected.

[image]

Is this impossible? If it is, does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Comment: are those virtual nic? 
In all cases you should be able to do this technically speaking: one subnet between the two C1/C2 and a default gateway to eth1 IP.

Comment: yes it is all virtual. but when i create a subnet using docker it also creates a bridge

Comment: "_it also creates a bridge_" Bridges are transparent devices, so you are basically directly connecting any devices connected to a bridge. An ethernet switch is a bridge, and while devices connected to a switch are electrically isolated, at the data-link layer, they are directly connected because the switch is transparent to the data-link layer.

Comment: not at the network level however at the application level you can make C1 become a reverse proxy server which forwards traffic to C2 so outside world only sees C1 and C2 is not reachable unless routed through C1 ... either roll your own or use something like nginx for such a server in C1 ... this approach works cross platform

Answer (score 0):

You can, at least on linux. But not with docker itself. You can create pair of veth devices, and push one of them to c1 container's network namespace, and another one side of veth to c2 container's ns. Make sure you assigned ips to that adapters and configured proper forwarding/routes/nat.